# Workflow not Triggering with No Errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-list

I have many things that I think are going on but no sure what the problem may be.

**Problem:** Created a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 to send an email when something is added to a list.  Then I added a pause to wait until an column changes to "Done" and another email is sent.  The problem is that the initial email is not been sent to the person assigned person all of the time.  It sometimes sends and other times doesn't.  When I look at the workflow status for the items where the assigned person never received the email - the workflow reads "in-progress" with no errors.  To me that shows that the email was sent and now it's waiting for status column to be "Done".  But that is not true. The workflow may be "in-progress" but did not send the initial email.  Again this is not consistent.  Sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. Also, it doesn't work more with a particular assigned person that others.

**What I tried:** To try to fix the issue or figure out what's going on I have checked the workflow history.  There are over 1,000 items in the history.  Not sure if this is causing the issue.  I have also check to make sure those being assigned have the proper permissions to the page.  I also checked the error logs.  Nothing.

Can anyone help me with this?  I am not sure if it's a looping issue since I am using "Pause" but this the initial email that should be sent when a new item is added to the list.

Comment: Just to confirm what I understand. 1) The workflow email before wait action is sending out except one person? 2) Because of failure in the question 1 after status change to done second email is not sending?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti There are two workflows on the list.  The first workflow is the one not working.  The first workflow is to trigger when a new item is added to the list.  It is to send an email to the assigned person of the list item.  The second workflow is another email that is sent when the status changes to done.  The first workflow is the one that I cannot seem to figure out.  It triggers sometimes.  Then there are times when the workflow status saids in progress but the first email was never sent

Comment: Can you log the email address before you sent an email?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti Sounds interesting.  Can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: Before the `send an email` action just log the `Assigned Person` email to workflow history?

Comment: Did not think of that but that means that the problem could be that I am logging the history after the second workflow completes.  So logging the history first will fix the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61397/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-sharepoint-lady).